# Visual Studio 2012 empty line after brace

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012

When writing CSS in VS2012 empty lines are automatically removed. For instance when I write

```
.class {
    *empty*
}

.class {
}
```

The closing brace will auto move up one line. I cannot disable this anywhere in the options. Anyone idea's how to disable this?

Comment: What semicolon? You mean _brace_?

Comment: Can I ask why you would like the empty line? I understand readability might be a factor, but it's really not that hard to read. For production purposes, I would imagine you would remove the empty classes anyway.

Comment: @ColeJohnson sorry.. I was sort of sleeping I think..

Comment: @Danexxtone Its just a way of coding I am used to. I create the selector, open it with braces and add the properties.

Comment: Is pushing <Enter> really _that hard_ though? Anyways, what extensions do you have? Have you tried disabling them one by one to find the culprit?

Comment: The <Enter> is what causes de empty line but that's not the point. The point is that VS2012 obligates me to use this style of programming and I don't want to.. I disabled all of them so that's why I know its build in VS2012.

Comment: Doesn't look like you can disable it. Maybe a snippet might work?